# How to put values in a Website table using python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, html-table

I am trying to key in certain values in website table and I was able to do it with the below code, However the value is hovering over the table and is not getting pasted in the table.

That is, I am able to see the value in the input field in the table but as soon as I click it, the value disappears.

put_val = browser.find_element_by_xpath('xpath provided here')

browser.execute_script('arguments[0].innerHTML = "89898989";', put_val)

Can anyone please help me with this issue ?

Comment: Usually to pass values we use send_keys method for input tag. Anyway, need more info about your table structure. Can you show what the part where you place your values looks like?

Comment: I did try send_keys method and it did not work at all. So I looked up this method online and it worked but not the way I wanted it to.

This is where I want to key in the value:
<input type="text" class="k-input k-textbox" name="prt_nbr" data-bind="value:prt_nbr" maxlength="15" style="text-transform: uppercase">